# Is it possible to get all the messages I sent on Facebook messenger?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API with Python. I'm able to request some basic information about my own profile such as birthday and location with:

```
events = graph.request('me?fields=location,birthday')
```

I was wondering is it possible to also request all the messages we sent through Facebook Messenger?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

API access to user messages has been removed long ago.

Only page conversations can be accessed via API.